# Flutter snapshot.data() always null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm trying to display my Data from Firestore in my Flutter Web App, but I don't get any data.

Basically I just adjusted this example: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DataList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataListState createState() => _DataListState();
}

class _DataListState extends State<DataList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data');

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: collectionReference.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        print('HasData: ${snapshot.hasData}');

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        return new ListView(
           children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document.data()['name']),
              subtitle: new Text(document.data()['description']),
              );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But snapshot.hasData is always null and I get this error:
`[cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'`

Getting a single Document works fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class GetData extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetData(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: collectionReference.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return Text("Name: ${data['name']}, Description: ${data['description']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I don't really need it to be Realtime, btw.

Comment: I am having the same issue, exact same error. Can read documents but not collections.  Latest flutter beta (1.23.0-18.1.pre) and Cloud Firestore package (0.14.3).

Comment: Also I should mention that iOS and Android work fine, it only gives this error when running on web.

Comment: Now being tracked on the flutter fire issues page: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4127

Comment: 1st - in issue description there is method ( `hasData()` )  while in the code presented there is field `snapshot.hasData`; 2nd - neither the mentioned example nor the API reference for `QuerySnapshot` does not have any `hasData` property/method. Are you sure the code is ok?

Comment: @vitooh You're right, hasData isn't a method, i just messed this up. The hasData property is part of AsyncSnapshot. But still that's not really the problem, since the print Statement isn't needed at all.

Comment: Does it work in `StatelessWidget` as in tutorial example and single document example as well?

Comment: downgrade your firebase js sdk in index.html file

Comment: you can use 7.22.1

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your firestore script in `index.html` file with this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```